# Animation frames flash if animation is split with `\only`

Tags: beamer, animate

I gave a [talk](https://github.com/habi/talk.2022.MICResearchDay) in which I 'paused' movies/animation using `\only`.
When going to the next animation step, the first frame of the previous animation flashes for a split-second, 'destroying' the illusion of a pause...

I *know* that a MWE is expected, but struggle to find a way of providing fully self-contained code, since it would need to have access to the movie frames [1] to show the issue.

The idea is that I want to pause the movie for the listeners and continue it with stepping trough the presentation.

The relevant code at the moment is:

```
\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{%
        \animategraphics[autoplay]{24}{./video-0}{000}{150}%
    }%
    \only<2>{%
        \animategraphics[autoplay]{24}{./video-0}{150}{171}%
    }%
    \only<3>{%
        \animategraphics[autoplay]{24}{./video-0}{171}{300}%
    }%
\end{frame}
```

I also tried to `autopause` the animations which - according to the documentation of the animate package - should "Pause [the] animation when the page is closed, instead of stopping and rewinding it to the default frame.", but that didn't help.

Does anyone here more versed with animating frames see a possibility to avoid flashing the listeners of my talk with 'old' frames?

[1]: which are 300 single frames...

Comment: There is pkg `mwe` that provides example images. For the present case I suggest using the multipage file `example-movie.pdf` for making an MWE with `\animategraphics` and `beamer`. It provides 61 frames which should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; for the moment I minimized the code online in this branch: https://github.com/habi/Talk.2022.MICResearchDay/tree/mwe-animation-flash

Comment: Interesting: In Okular on Linux, there is no flashing back to the first frame. The transition to the subsequent part of the animation is smooth when going to the next page.

Comment: And the same in Acrobat Reader on a Windows Server (connected to with rdesktop).

Comment: Strangely, I also do not see the flashing issue when compiling the code and viewing the PDF on a Linux machine today. I did present the talk with Acrobat Reader on OSX yesterday, but said machine is at home at the moment, so I can only test it again tonight. It might boil down to an Acrobat Reader issue in the end...

Comment: Here's the movie shown with Adobe Acrobat DC 2022.002.20142 on OS X 12.4 (21F79): https://youtu.be/EyksKG81LyE The flashing frame is visible :(

Comment: For those who care, here's a build of the presentation online: https://github.com/habi/Talk.2022.MICResearchDay/actions/runs/2589319368 (it's rather big at 0.5 GB...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might indeed depend on the device that the animation is run on.

Unfortunately, `autopause` is not effective anymore as soon as the animation has reached the end. The problem can be worked around by explicitly pausing the animation after the last frame. This prevents winding back to the start on page change. However this requires adding an animation timeline or using `animateinline` with a pausing `\newframe*`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
%\graphicspath{{./images/VETSUISSE/HorseLimb/Limb02/frames/}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\zeropad#1#2{%
  \ifnum1#2<1#1
    \zeropad{#1}{0#2}%
  \else%
    #2%
  \fi%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\imheight}{0.618\paperheight}

\begin{frame}{Before Hoof}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Hoof}
    \only<1>{%
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{24}
      \multiframe{151}{i=0+1}{\includegraphics[height=\imheight]{video-\zeropad{0000}{\i}}}%
      \newframe*
      \includegraphics[height=\imheight]{video-0150} % last frame needs to be repeated
    \end{animateinline}
    }%
    \only<2>{%
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{24}
      \multiframe{22}{i=150+1}{\includegraphics[height=\imheight]{video-\zeropad{0000}{\i}}}%
      \newframe* 
      \includegraphics[height=\imheight]{video-0171} % last frame needs to be repeated
    \end{animateinline}
    }%
    \only<3>{%
    \animategraphics[autoplay,height=\imheight]{24}{video-}{0171}{0300}%
    }%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: NB: In order to repeat the three overlays it is necessary to go back to the slide *before* the  first overlay by means of the Back key on the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this in detail. Your workaround is quite elegant and I will employ it if I want to 'split' movies like this in future presentations.